# vs_buildtools.exe missing from Visual Studio Build Tools 2017

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msbuild, visual-studio-2017

I [installed](https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/) the Visual Studio Build Tools 2017 using the link (at bottom under Other Tools and Frameworks) installing both workloads: Visual C++ build tools and Web development build tools. I kept the default folder.

Based on quite a few articles, such as [Microsoft Web Application Targets is Missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44061932/ms-build-2017-microsoft-webapplication-targets-is-missing), I expected to see vs_buildtools.exe in the folder: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\MSBuild\15.0\Bin` folder, but no. I see MSBuild.exe, as you can see from this screenshot.

[image]

Here is a screenshot of the installer.

[image]

Really, there are quite a few articles saying the exact same thing: [1](https://github.com/cake-build/cake/issues/1369), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42696948/how-can-i-install-the-vs2017-version-of-msbuild-on-a-build-server-without-instal), to name only 2.

How do I get vs_buildtools.exe?

Apparently the only way to solve my Microsoft induced Web Application Targets missing problem, as it is no longer in 15.0 is to use this executable and run the `vs_buildtools.exe --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.WebBuildTools` as the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44061932/ms-build-2017-microsoft-webapplication-targets-is-missing) specifies. I am also annoyed now that something that should be there is not. Did Microsoft change something in a newer revision of the Build Tools?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> How do I get vs_buildtools.exe?

You have already got the vs_buildtools.exe.

> I installed the Visual Studio Build Tools 2017 using the link (at bottom under Other Tools and Frameworks) installing both workloads

You will notice that the installed file name is **vs_buildtools__339506979.1501125082.exe**, which include the version info in the name. You can rename it to vs_buildtools.exe, that is what you want.

**Update for vs_buildtools.exe:**

[image]

After use the command:

`vs_buildtools.exe --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.WebBuildTools`

The WebBuildTools will be installed at:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\WebApplications
```

Besides, be aware that the comment under the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44061932/ms-build-2017-microsoft-webapplication-targets-is-missing):

> If you already have downloaded the "Build Tools for Visual Studio
>   2017" installer
>   (visualstudio.com/thank-you-downloading-visual-studio/…), then you can
>   launch that installer, hit Modify and tick the "Web development build
>   tasks" workload module checkbox. Then click the Modify button and let
>   the installer finish.

Comment: Thank you for the response, however I do not see the executable. I gave a screenshot sorting by type in my question showing that I do not already have the file, at least that I can see and search. There are only 3 executable files in the bin folder. In the folder, which you referenced there is also no vs_build*.exe. I went to "C:\Program Files (x86)" and did a search for vs_build*.exe and that came up empty, just to make sure.

Comment: By default, I am showing hidden files as well as file extensions.

Comment: @SarahWeinberger, The file (Visual Studio Build Tools 2017 ) you have downloaded from this link: https://www.visualstudio.com/thank-you-downloading-visual-studio/?sku=BuildTools&rel=15 is what you want. But the file name include the version info.

Comment: @SarahWeinberger, I have update my answer with more info, please check if it works for you.

Comment: Okay, I feel dumb now. It never crossed my mind even in the slightest that the vs_build.exe file IS the physical downloaded setup file. I thought that was a file to be instantly deleted after installation and that vs_build.exe is a different file. Now the other answers make sense, sort of. I am not following why I need both workflows previously installed prior to executing the command to get the damn web targets, though that seems to be installed, just in a different place. Thank you for the update!

Comment: @SarahWeinberger, This information is not explicitly stated in this blog:https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2016/11/16/introducing-the-visual-studio-build-tools/, only speculated from this sentence "Navigate to the installer’s directory ....". BTW, I found you also have post the same question on MSDN,https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/26d0266c-e642-4c1d-a42c-ba8a69c40667/vsbuildtoolsexe-missing-in-visual-studio-build-tools-2017?forum=msbuild. if possible, could you mark the answer, so that we could close that thread on MSDN. Thanks.

Comment: @Leo_MSFT Every post kept saying "vs_buildtools.exe" not "vs_buildtools_******.exe". That threw me off along with Microsoft, one must always install and then use an executable, not the setup program itself. That is weird enough that one of the zillion posts should have made this distinction. Also, vs_buildtools.exe does not technically exist, so all those zillion articles are wrong. The file name is vs_buildtools_*****.exe" and is an installer/setup program, not a tool. Thanks again Leo.