# dotnet build UWP.sln | error MSB4019 Microsoft.Windows.UI.Xaml.CSharp.targets not found

Tags: .net, .net-core, uwp

I have an `uwp` project in my solution. I actually get the following error when trying to build it via `dotnet build`:

> D:\MyFooProject.csproj(184,3): error MSB4019: Das importierte Projekt "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\5.0.100-preview.5.20279.10\Microsoft\WindowsXaml\v16.0\Microsoft.Windows.UI.Xaml.CSharp.targets" wurde nicht gefunden. Stellen Sie sicher, dass der Ausdruck in der Import-Deklaration "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\5.0.100-preview.5.20279.10\Microsoft\WindowsXaml\v16.0\Microsoft.Windows.UI.Xaml.CSharp.targets" richtig ist und dass die Datei auf dem Datenträger vorhanden ist.

The `csproj` entry:

`<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Microsoft\WindowsXaml\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\Microsoft.Windows.UI.Xaml.CSharp.targets" />`

As already discussed ([Microsoft.Windows.UI.Xaml.CSharp.targets missing on CI server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45041972/microsoft-windows-ui-xaml-csharp-targets-missing-on-ci-server)), it would be possible to build if I copy `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Microsoft\WindowsXaml\v16.0\Microsoft.Windows.UI.Xaml.CSharp.Targets` on my ci server.

Is there something wrong with my plans or does `dotnet` currently not support `uwp`? Because it is not possible to create an uwp project via `dotnet new`.

Comment: does dotnet currently not support uwp? Yes. Kind of obvious. Call MSBuild to compile such projects instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UWP is currently not compatible with .NET Core and its command-line interface (CLI) so using `dotnet` to build a UWP is not going to work very well I am afraid.

You should either use Visual Studio or MSBuild from the command-line to build your app.